# Chaining async tasks on Angular

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise, broadcast, ionic-framework

### Goal

What i am doing is chaining various asynchronous tasks that depend on the response of the previous ones to finally get an Array of objects that wrap all the responses to be used in the `$scope`. I am using `Angular` and `MongoDB`.

### Logic

So, i have multiple `Url` that are associated to a specific `User` using `UserUrl` models. Each `Url` is as well associated to a `Group` using `GroupUrl` models. **The client will see a list of `Groups` but every item in the list shows data of `UserUrl` and the `GroupUrl` belonging to each `Group`.**

For this i am using `promises` and a `Broadcast Service`.

First i get all the `UserUrls`:

```
allUrlByUser( $scope.user )
    .then( function(userUrls){
      angular.forEach( userUrls, function(userUrl){
          allUrlById(userUrl);
      });
    });
```

Foreach `Userurl` i resolve the `Url` itself:

```
allUrlById = function( userUrl )
  {
      return ajaxService
              .api( 'allUrlById',userUrl.url )
              .then( function( url )
              {
                var wrap = {
                  url : url[0],
                  userUrl: userUrl
                };
                /*
                Emit message passing a object response built 
                using previous and current async data.
                */
                Messenger.call(Messenger.allUrlById,
                  wrap);  
              });
```

The observer of the emitted message is:

```
$scope.$on(Messenger.allUrlById, function(e,msg) {
    return allGroupUrlById(msg);
  });
```

And the callback function is:

```
allGroupUrlById = function( msg )
  {
      return ajaxService
              .api( 'allGroupUrlById', msg.response.url._id )
              .then( function( groupUrl )
              {
                var wrap = {
                  url : msg.response.url,
                  userUrl: msg.response.userUrl,
                  group : groupUrl[0].group
                };
                $scope.groups.push(wrap);
              });
  }
```

### Questions

Taking into account i need a final array of wrapped objects mixing data of multiple asynchronous tasks:

- Is this a proper/acceptable way of doing it?
- Do you think this technique will sufficiently perform on big ammounts of queries?
- Any suggestions?

Comment: but does not $q.all asume we have all the required option values before hand? I mean, i have 3 async tasks and the 2nd one needs the result of the 1st one, the 3rd one needs the 2nd one.. can $q.all still be used in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, although it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Broadcast Service, promise is enough:

```
allUrlByUser( $scope.user ).then(function(userUrls){
    angular.forEach( userUrls, function(userUrl){
        allUrlById(userUrl).then(function(result) {
            allGroupUrlById(result);
        });
    });
});

allUrlById = function( userUrl ) {
    return ajaxService
          .api( 'allUrlById',userUrl.url )
          .then( function( url ) {
              return {
                  url : url[0],
                  userUrl: userUrl
              };
          });
}

allGroupUrlById = function(result) {
    return ajaxService
          .api( 'allGroupUrlById', result.url._id )
          .then( function( groupUrl ) {
              var wrap = {
                  url : result.url,
                  userUrl: result.userUrl,
                  group : groupUrl[0].group
              };
              $scope.groups.push(wrap);
          });
}
```

Comment: This does the operations one by one, is this what OP wants?